# jq find image and remove next tag

Tags: jquery

I have a problem where wordpress gives seperate p tags where it should not, throwing the image out of the paragraph and not making if float where it should.

So I get

```
<p> <img /> </p> <p> TEXT </p>
```

instead of

```
<p> <img /> TEXT </p>.
```

This works in 1 theme how it should, but not in the mobile theme and I have no idea where the problem is, and I think it would be easier to have a jq script find the image it should (depending on the src) and then delete the next `</p>` and `<p>`.

Comment: jQuery works by manipulating the DOM, not the HTML -- so it's not possible for it to remove just a closing tag.

Your problem can probably be solved with CSS, but it's hard to say what the best approach should be without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Are there any classes exposed by these elements (or an ancestor) that can allow us to restrict our selectors? You probably do not want this to happen for all the images in your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your markup, you can indeed achieve your goal with jQuery. As I commented under your question, you will probably want to restrict the `p > img` selector used in the code below in some way, unless you do want all images in your document to trigger the DOM update.

That said, it's a simple matter of matching the [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) of the [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) `<p>` element after the one containing an image, then [reparenting](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) it under the first one, then removing the second one.

However, since removing an element does not break its descendant tree, we can actually [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the second `<p>` element before reparenting its contents, which allows us to chain the whole operation into:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p > img").each(function() {
        var $p = $(this).parent();
        $p.next("p").remove().contents().appendTo($p);
    });
});
```

You can test the code above in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejWH6/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works in my example - however, I`m new to jq so I`m not sure how to find the exact image based on the source. Also, the empty p tags from the image stay inside the html and I get some extra space - am I able to remove them? And finally, the p > img would mean something like for each image that is inside a p tag, right? Im guessing that I would need something like .src(image source here) instead of the .each() then? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry - there are some extra empty p tags so I thought it was from the image, the jq actually does remove those ones I want removed.

Answer (score 0):

as @lbazemonger said, more code is necessary to look into.

Remember, when using the_content() in wordpress, the entire output is always encased in

as it should be.

and, if I am not mistaken, so is html that you write in a wordpress escaped, beforehand, so you don't end up with duplicate

.

I would assume that the mobile version might have something like this going on:

```
<p>
  <?php the_content();?>
</p>
```

Comment: The mobile version has no p tags around it, just a div
I don't have enough code, and the problem is that a number of functions are called, many of them I have no idea from where, if I knew where the parsing is done I could be able to do something but as this is my first wp project, I have no idea what is going on
I would post the wp/php but there is so many of it on so many places that I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0):

What if you unload the output of wordpress into a div and then manipulate with JQ the html code.